# Highlight very simple code tag in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting

In a self hosted wordpress blog, I'm trying to hightlight this code : `[xml]`, inline.

If I put this :

```
[code language="ps" light="true"][xml][/code]
```

It outputs as `1`

Which html source is :

```
<div class="line number1 index0 alt2">
    <code class="powershell plain">1</code>
</div>
```

How can I tell the syntaxt highlight engine to ignore the `[xml]` tag and render it as is?

Is it possible to hightlight some words in a sentence? (like the ``code`` construct in SO)

**[edit]** I also tried :

```
[code language="ps" light="true"]&#x5B;xml][/code]
```

But it outputs `&#x5B;xml]`

Comment: The answer would depend on the plugin you are using for syntax highlighting. WordPress itself doesn't do that.

Comment: I use syntax hightlighter, same as [the hosted version](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin to highlight code snippets

https://wordpress.org/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/

Comment: Thanks... crayon looks like to solve my issues. However, it suppose I rewrite all my previous articles, because both syntax highlighter seems to be conflicting :'(

Comment: Ok... the settings of the plugins seems to provides a "Convert legacy tag". I'll give it a try